# Members arent cached

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a selfbot and before receiving messages saying that's against Discord ToS, I take that risk. My bot sends messages only to people it already has a DM channel opened with, probably because members aren't cached.

I want my bot to send message to everyone in my server. How do I cache members on a selfbot?

Code:

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("id");

if(!guild) return;

guild.members.fetch();

guild.members.cache.random().createDM().then((dm => {
  dm.send("Dont forget to verify !").catch(e => console.log('error'))
})).catch(() => {});

console.log("message sent");
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? Are you getting an error message of some sort? As it's currently written, your question is unable to be answered accurately.

Answer (score 0):

[Server Members Intent Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLzdR.png)

Image above shows example to this answer;

Did you enable SERVER MEMBERS INTENT when creating your Discord bot?
`https://discord.com/developers/applications/"ClientId"/bot`

And/or did you create a new discord client with the GUILD_MEMBERS intent?

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ]
});
```

And whether or not you know the risks, you should NOT be using self bots.

Comment: As the OP *clearly* states, this is NOT a bot, it's a selfbot. No "Intents" can be set because it is running from their user account, so this is not at all relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Also you need `Guilds` intent as well. Only `GuildMembers` is not enough